# Python edifact library won't work on windows 10

Tags: python, edifact

Hello and thanks in advance,

Python is a languge I don't often use but I am interested in an edifact library called [pydifact](https://github.com/nerdocs/pydifact) I found on github. I run the example, it runs fine on linux but I get an error on windows 10... I used python 3.10

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python\testApp.py", line 1, in <module>
from pydifact.segmentcollection import Interchange
File "c:\users\myname\pydifact\pydifact\__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
from pydifact import segmentcollection, parser, segments, serializer, token, 
tokenizer
File "c:\users\myname\pydifact\pydifact\segmentcollection.py", line 339, in <module>
class Interchange(FileSourcableMixin, UNAHandlingMixin, AbstractSegmentsContainer):
File "c:\users\myname\pydifact\pydifact\segmentcollection.py", line 425, in Interchange
cls, segments: Union[list, collections.Iterable]
AttributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute 'Iterable'
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line

```py
cls, segments: Union[list, collections.Iterable]
```

which the error message mentions, indicates, that `Iterable` is not in `collections` module. Python deprecated `colections.<smth>` in favor of `collections.abc.<smth>` since version 3.3. Since 3.10 this deprecated behaviour is completely dropped and raises an error.

So, you should downgrade to python 3.9 or eariler or replace all occurences of

```py
collections.Iterable
```

to

```py
collections.abc.Iterable
```

Comment: Yes it worked. Thanks a lot! The python version on my linux machine was 3.9.5 that's why it worked. I downgraded the version on my windows machine and it worked as well...